# Determine if Intent from Intent.createChooser will start Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I am creating an intent via the `createChooser` method and I need to know if the Intent return from this will start Facebook.

Is there a property on the Intent that will inform me of this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a property on the Intent that will inform me of this?

Not really.

You are welcome to peek at `getComponent()` and see if it is Facebook, by whatever fragile algorithm you wish to use to determine what is and is not Facebook.

However, if there is more than one `<intent-filter>` match for your `Intent` that you pass into `createChooser()`, the `Intent` that you get back will point to the system-supplied chooser activity. At this point, all you have is an `Intent`, and the user has not chosen one of the candidate activities. Whether the user chooses Facebook or something else is up to the user and the system's chooser activity; you are not informed.

If you need more control than that, implement your own chooser using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.